# How to get DOM of a vue component without rendering it?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

Suppose I have a simple Vue component like this:

```js
Vue.component('blog-post', {
  props: ['title'],
  template: '<h3>{{ title }}</h3>'
})
```

I don't want to render the component. I just want to pass the `title` somehow into `blog-post` component inside my script code, and get the DOM accordingly. For example, if I pass the title value `Hello`, then I expected the full DOM as `<h3>Hello</h3>`. I'll assign the DOM into a variable for using later.

Comment: If you expect full dom <h3>hello</h3> create a different component that will give you what you want. When you need blog-post component, render it separately.

Comment: Actually, my goal is to create a component and passing that into a map as a custom box.
https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk/addcustominfobox

Comment: Perhaps you want to look at PortalVue? https://portal-vue.linusb.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to create a new Vue instance with only the target component, [`$mount`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-mount) it, and then get the [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) of its [`$el` (root element)](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-el):

#### Vue 2

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<script>
Vue.component('blog-post', {
  props: ['title'],
  template: '<h3>{{ title }}</h3>'
})

const app = new Vue({
  template: `<blog-post title="Hello world" />`
}).$mount()

console.log(app.$el.outerHTML)
</script>
```

#### Vue 3

In Vue 3, [create an app instance](https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#createapp), and call its [`mount()`](https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-mount) on a newly created `<div>`. The return value of `mount()` is the root component, which contains `$el`:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.39/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<script>
const app = Vue.createApp({
  template: `<blog-post title="Hello world" />`
})

app.component('blog-post', {
  props: ['title'],
  template: '<h3>{{ title }}</h3>'
})

const comp = app.mount(document.createElement('div'))

console.log(comp.$el.outerHTML)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get HTML of your component, you must to use [ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements) attribute of parent element.

Try something like that:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <div>
        <button @click="logComponentBlogPost">Log Component</button>
      </div>

      <div v-show="false" ref="BlogPost">
        <blog-post title="Hello Word"></blog-post>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      let BlogPost = Vue.component('BlogPost', {
        props: ['title'],
        template: '<h3>{{ title }}</h3>',
      });

      new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        components: { BlogPost },
        methods: {
          logComponentBlogPost() {
            console.log(this.$refs.BlogPost.innerHTML);
          },
        },
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The OP wants to get a component's HTML without having to render the component beforehand.

Comment: Are you sure? Attention in this section: "If I pass the title value Hello then I expected the full dom as <h3>Hello</h3>"

Comment: See title. And the last paragraph in the question starts with: "I don't want to render the component."

Comment: In my example, the component is not shown, but the browser needs to process the component to get the result he want.

Comment: Actually, you are rendering the component in a hidden manner.